# Import path was added as an Endpoint

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am a newbie in Javascript. How can I import in javascript with node js?.

I imported A custom Element:

```
import UserView from "./Component/UserView";

window.customElements.define("user-view", UserView);
```

Then get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:4000/Component/UserView net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I can just use res.sendfile in node js to send the file (if its possible). It seems the path was added as an endpoint instead. I would like to import it directly but instead I got the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nodejs has no native `window` object, so that doesn't look like it is a script being run in nodejs, but a script run from the client side. And since it is run client side any imported file needs to be retrieved hence why you get a `GET` request message

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import` try `require.resolve()` on the path you're requesting. I'm still pretty sure what you're trying cannot work though.